# Webpage with embedded flutter app does not handle touch after flutter iframe gets touched

Tags: reactjs, typescript, flutter, iframe, touch-event

We have a React web application that shows an iframe on the right side if opened. This iframe is filled with a flutter app. If the iframe is opened and the user touches inside the flutter app, then touches somewhere else on the web application, the touch does nothing. Closing/hiding iframe with the flutter app will give back touch control to the web app.
onTouch events do get triggered (console.logs onTouchStart show up on touch), but nothing happens.
Using a mouse with click events does not cause any issues.

Has anyone encountered this problem too? I'm no Flutter developer and the developer of the flutter app has no idea :') so I'm hoping someone has a golden tip on what to do here?

Comment: Revealing some code would help, I guess there must be some eventlisteners in `iframe`